# Bind a JSON string data to details view

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, json

I actually passed a JSON string to the script and would like to display it in a detailsview.

This is what my jquery looks like

```
    function onBeforeClientInsert(record) {


    var eventtype = parseInt(record.<%= CEO.FieldEvaluator.GetEvaluatorByDId("EVENT_TYPE_ID").GetFieldDataFieldId()%>);
   var begindate = record.<%= CEO.FieldEvaluator.GetEvaluatorByDId("BeginDate").GetFieldDataFieldId()%>;
   var enddate = record.<%= CEO.FieldEvaluator.GetEvaluatorByDId("EndDate").GetFieldDataFieldId()%>;

     $.ajax({
            type: "POST", url: "Data.aspx/CheckInsertRecord",
            data: "{EventType:'" + eventtype + "',BeginDate:'" + begindate + "'," +
                   "EndDate:'" + enddate+"' }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                 if(msg.d == "No duplicate"){

                 }
                 else{
                     alert(msg.d);
                     eval("var data = "+msg.d+";");
                     alert(data[0].BeginDate);
                     alert(data[0].EVENT_TYPE_ID);
                  }
                  var modal = document.getElementById('Div1');
        modal.style.display = '';
        modal.style.position = 'fixed';
        modal.style.zIndex = '100';
        modal.style.left = '30%';
        modal.style.top = '40%';

                   var screen = document.getElementById('modalScreen');
        screen.style.display = '';

            }

        });
```

modalScreen just creates a popup. This is what Div1 consists of

```
         <div style="display: none; background-color: White; width: 450px; height: 150px;"
                    id="Div1">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="HI" runat="server"></asp:Label>
   <asp:DetailsView ID="de" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="True" Height="50px" Width="301px">
   <Fields>
   <asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval(data[0].EVENT_TYPE_ID) %>'></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   </Fields>

    </asp:DetailsView>
    <input type="button" onclick="Hide()" value="OK" />
</div>
```

This is mycodebehind:

```
     public static string CheckInsertRecord(String EventType, String BeginDate, String EndDate)
{
    NCDCPoint ncdc = new NCDCPoint();
    CEOSurveyDataContext CDC = new CEOSurveyDataContext();
    int et = Convert.ToInt32(EventType);
    CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    DateTime b = Convert.ToDateTime(BeginDate);
    DateTime e = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate);
    DetailsView a = new DetailsView();

      var query = (from n in CDC.NCDCPoints
                where n.EVENT_TYPE_ID == et && n.BeginDate == b && n.EndDate == e
                select new { 
                   n.EVENT_TYPE_ID,
              BeginDate =  n.BeginDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd",provider),
               EndDate = n.EndDate.ToString(),
                n.BeginLAT,
              BeginLONG =  n.BeginLONG,
                n.EndLAT,
                n.EndLONG});

   if (query.Any())
   {
       return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(query.ToList());
   }
   else
   {
       return "No duplicate";
   }
```

}

So, I can't access data variable inside Div1. So can u guys let me know how i can deal with this?

Moreover, query that I wrote in the codebehind is what I need to display? So, can u figure me out any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is display some information via AJAX you do not need to use a details view, which is a server side control. If you really want to use that you need to use an [update panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and [partial page postback](http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax) to populate the control. You are better of the way you are headed though.

First up your HTML should be along the lines of:

```
<div id="Div1" style="display: none; background-color: White; width: 450px; height: 150px;position:fixed;zIndex:100;left30%;top40%;>
    <div>Begin Date:<span id="beginDate"></span></div>
    <div>EventTypeID:<span id="eventTypeID"></span></div> 
</div>
```

There is no reason not to fully style Div1 That I can See

Your jQuery should be more like:

```
    function onBeforeClientInsert(record) {  
        var eventtype = parseInt(record.<%= CEO.FieldEvaluator.GetEvaluatorByDId("EVENT_TYPE_ID").GetFieldDataFieldId()%>);
        var begindate = record.<%= CEO.FieldEvaluator.GetEvaluatorByDId("BeginDate").GetFieldDataFieldId()%>;
        var enddate = record.<%= CEO.FieldEvaluator.GetEvaluatorByDId("EndDate").GetFieldDataFieldId()%>;

         $.ajax({
            type: "POST", url: "Data.aspx/CheckInsertRecord",
            data: "{EventType:'" + eventtype + "',BeginDate:'" + begindate + "'," +
                   "EndDate:'" + enddate+"' }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                 if(msg.d == "No duplicate"){

                 }
                 else{
                     alert(msg.d);
                     var data  = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d); //safer than eval
                     alert(data[0].BeginDate);
                     alert(data[0].EVENT_TYPE_ID);
                  }

                  //Set the values
                  $("#beginDate").html(data[0].BeginDate);
                  $("#eventTypeID").html(data[0].EVENT_TYPE_ID);

                  //Show Divs
                  $("#Div1").show();
                  $("#modalScreen").show();

            }

        });
```

From the look of it you should do a little more reading on jQuery. Have a look at [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), [CSS](http://api.jquery.com/category/css/), [Effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) and [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).

Comment: I just tried the way you told me but I'm not able to get begindate value